# Scrolling appears on my PageScroll. How to disable it?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uipageviewcontroller

I did it from here: [Third part of tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/76436/use-uiscrollview-scroll-zoom-content-swift)

But how you can see on screenshot, there scrolls appears and I do not switch images like a page, just scroll it. How to disable scrolling and switch images like a page?

This is scrollView and I turn on Paging and Scrolling enabled
[image]

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Please specify what exactly you want to achieve and also attach screenshots of where the problem is.

Comment: Your content seems to be too large, and that is why you are having scrolling. I can see vertical scrolling and horizontal scrolling as well. Can you please try with assets which fit inside a page. From your screenshots its not very clear.

Comment: But what about, if I'll open this on iPhone6 Plus and iPhone 4. It will scrolls again, no? So, how can I fit them?

Comment: Well if you are loading assets from the resources, then you would need to cut images specific to each phone more like image.png, image@2x.png, and image@3x.png. If you are loading assets from the internet, then you would need to smartly manage the frame of each item in your page.

Comment: @GurtejSingh, no I load them from the assets. Thanks! I'll try now with @ 2x and @ 3x

Comment: Sure. Try to smartly cut your images. I would still recommend you apply frame on the individual pages to fit the screen

Comment: @GurtejSingh but what is the sizes for it?

Answer (score 0):

scrl.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
scrl.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;

Comment: I think that's not a solution. In that case it will crop my images. I do not want it